# unRAID equivalent in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid

On my Ubuntu home server, I have 2 RAID5 arrays (mdadm), one is 3x4TB, the other 4x4TB. I need to increase size and I am now contemplating migrating to unRAID for its ability to grow arrays more efficiently (financially speaking) by simply adding disks that can be of different sizes.

Is there a solution for Linux that could allow me to create an array similar to what is possible in unRAID? (disk of different sizes, easy to add/replace disk)

I saw that ZFS does not get the flexibility, Btrfs seems still too experimental.